# 7zip destination folder -o

Tags: zip, 7zip

I have wondered a long time how to do this and read already many manuals but dont get this to work. I want to zip with 7zip a folder to specific destination. There is in manual a guide to use -o{folder} but how does it really work?

Example:

```
7z a -t7z serverx /home/example/folder -o/home/backups/folder1
```

How to use that -o? Destination folder exists.

Comment: Are you getting some errors?

Comment: @ElderGeek: a space after `-o` leads to error `Too short switch: -o`.

Comment: **NOTE**:  tilda `~`  appears not to be resolved for some reason, use `-o/home/frank/someFolder` rather than `-o~/someFolder`. (encountered on a perfectly normal Ubuntu 18.04 with 7-zip 16.02)

Answer (score 19):

From `man 7z`:

```
   -o{Directory}
          Set Output directory
```

It is basically the destination directory for extracting the archive. All the extracted files will be saved in the given directory. This option won't be used in case of creating the archive.

Here is an example:

```
$ 7z a -t7z check.7z file.txt -ofoo/
Creating archive check.7z
Compressing  file.txt      
Everything is Ok

$ ls
check.7z  file.txt  foo

$ 7z x -t7z check.7z -ofoo/
Processing archive: check.7z
Extracting  file.txt
Everything is Ok
Size:       180
Compressed: 221

foo$ ls
file.txt
```

Comment: imho, unusual syntax that path goes immediately after -o switch, e.g. -o/home/userName/Downloads

Comment: tnx. ugly syntax where the path goes immediately after -o. It also doesn't understand tilde '~' as a home directory (you can't use -o~/some_path)

Answer (score 6):

To extracts into a directory, **you must remove any spaces after the `-o`**
for example,

**Extract** zip file into a new or existing directory `dir1`:

```
7z x file.zip -o./dir1
```

**Compress** directory `dir1` to a new zip file:

```
7z a newfile.zip ./dir1
```

Answer (score 3):

To **add** all files from directory `/home/example/folder` to archive `archive.7z` in `/home/backups/folder1` use:

`7z a -t7z /home/backups/folder1/archive.7z /home/example/folder`

`-0` switch specifies a destination directory where files are to be **extracted**.

Comment: I think the reason it's confusing is how the destination path is listed *before* the source directory to be compressed as it usually source > destination

Comment: @Pixeli can you mark it as 'answered' if my post indeed did answer your questions?